# Conditional functions in by rownames in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, bioinformatics

I am relatively new to R and I am having some issues with a functon I want to make.
I have an expression table where columns are species names and the rows are gene IDs.

```
exptable:
          SPECIES1 SPECIES2 SPECIES3 SPECIES4 SPECIES5 SPECIES6
    GENE1     3        3        3        3        3        3
    GENE2     2        1        1        5        5        5
    GENE3     2        1        1        5        5        5
    GENE4     2        1        1        5        5        5
    GENE5     2        1        1        5        5        5
    GENE6     2        1        1        5        5        5
```

I also have a list containing gene IDs that are of interest.
Now I would like to extract some information by certain conditions. one of them for instance would be
If SPEC1 and SPEC2 both have a value for GENE1 > 1 AND SPEC3 - SPEC6 < 1 then the gene name should be pasted in another file

The two issues I am having here are
1.
How do I use a for look that takes the genelist as an input. I had no problem doing it with one name:

```
z = "GENEID1"
grep(z,rownames(stage_g)) -> i
exptableB[i,] -> GOI3 
as.data.frame(GOI3) -> GOM3
```

How Could I do something like this with a list of many gene names

2. I have had no issues applying one condition. But I am having some trouble doing it with multiple conditions.

So yeah, basically I would like to write a loop function that applies multiple conditions to the expression data of different genes and writes the gene names (rownames) into a list if they are true...
I hope I have stated my question in an understandable matter. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2):

`%in%` can be useful for 'vectorized' exact matches; logical operations `&`, `|` can help with combining conditions

```
geneids <- c("GENE1", "GENE6")
row_index_1 <- rownames(exptable) %in% geneids
row_index_2 <- exptable[, "SPECIES3"] - exptable[, "SPECIES6"] < 1
row_index <- row_index_1 & row_index_2
rownames(exptable)[row_index]
```